# Why does the compiler allow Convert.ToString() to be assigned to an integer?

Tags: c#, .net

I accidentally stumbled across something similar to the following in my code, it compiles fine but then obviously bombs at runtime:

```
dynamic fiftySixDynamic = 56;
int fiftySixInt = System.Convert.ToString(fiftySixDynamic);
```

Every overload of **Convert.ToString()** returns a string, so surely this shouldn't compile? What's going on here?

Comment: My recommendation is post this as a bug.. i'm not really sure which place it would go off hand.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic This is exactly what it's supposed to do.  If it *didn't* compile *that* would be a bug.

Comment: This highlights a weakness in C# - it is not clear to the programmer which expressions have type-checking turned off. The language designers did better with unsafe { }

Comment: @Servy don't care. broken expectations = bug.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic So you're saying you don't know the meaning of the word "bug" then.  Okay.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're using `dynamic` for the input to `Convert.ToString`.  Because an input is `dynamic`, the method binding and type checking is deferred to run-time, so the compiler doesn't see that the only possible return type is `string`.  The compiler basically stops all binding and type-checking at that point.

Even if you called `fiftySixInt = fiftySixDynamic.ToString()`, which *can't* have an overload that returns an `int`, you would not get any warning from the compiler.

One way to avoid compile-time bugs yet still allow for dynamic behavior is to cast the return:

```
int fiftySixInt = (string)System.Convert.ToString(fiftySixDynamic);
```

It looks redundant, but it tells the compiler to treat the return value as a `string` for binding purposes.  The method is still bound at run-time, so if the return type is *not* a string, you'd get a run-time exception, but downstream methods would get bound at compile-time.

Comment: Interesting! It's surprising that there was no warning in Visual Studio, nothing from ReSharper etc!

Comment: @JMK Therein lies the power, and the danger, of `dynamic`.

Comment: @JMK You're surprised that when you turned off the compiler and told it not to do any type checking that it didn't inform you that you're performing an operation that isn't valid for a given type?  If you want the compiler to tell you if the types of an operation are valid, don't turn it off.

Comment: A little off, but another reason to use `var` if you expect the correct type.

Comment: If you are interested, I was actually doing some Excel automation, and using var for everything. A little quirk of Excel Interop is that certain types (such as the WorkSheet) are dynamic if you use var, and need to be strongly typed!

Comment: @JMK `var` is not `dynamic`.  `var` just tells the compiler to infer the return type from the expression.  Many Excel methods return `object`, so you have to specify the actual type _at compile-time_ in order to bind methods in a type-safe manner.  `dynamic` does the same thing, but at run-time instead of compile-time.

Comment: @DStanley I know, but if you do something like `var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open("blah.xlsx"); var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[2];`, *workbook* will be an Excel.Workbook, *worksheet* will be dynamic unless you specify that it is an *Excel.WorkSheet*

Comment: @JMK OK so Workbooks.Open must return `dynamic` then.  I see what you mean now, I just wanted to be clear that `var` is not the same as `dynamic`.

Comment: @JMK just a FYI, using the Excel Interop like that for `xlsx` files is really considered depeciated. If you are working with `xlsx` you should use the managed [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) instead, it is faster and it does not require Excel to be installed on the computer you are working on. The only reason to still use the interop is if you are doing some really rare edge case stuff that 99% of users don't use (like executing VBA script during the editing of the file)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm working with older Excel files too

Comment: @DStanley yeah it does, easy to get tripped up if you aren't paying attention!

Comment: This does seem odd to me. I can understand that using int fiftySixInt = fiftySixDynamic.ToString() wouldn't be caught by the compiler because there's no way to know what data type will be returned by the ToString method on the dynamic. However, when using System.Convert.ToString I would expect the compiler to catch it. System.Convert.ToString would be known method that it would know has a return of string, regardless of the type that's passed in. I've only needed to use dynamic once but now I know this is something to watch for.

Comment: @Servy i'm certainly surprised by this. i would say this is a bug.

Comment: @Marc When you use `dynamic` you're deferring binding the method, because you don't know the parameters, so no, you don't know the return type of the method.  Since you don't know the return type of the method.  It could be literally anything, which is why that expression resolves to `dynamic`.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic You're surprised that if you tell the compiler to not do any type checking that it doesn't do any type checking?  The feature is in the language specifically to turn off type checking.  It was literally designed to do exactly this.  If you want the compiler to do type checking, then don't explicitly turn off type checking   It's not a bug that when you go out of your way to prevent the compiler from doing type checking that it doesn't do type checking.

Comment: @Marc: You say "`System.Convert.ToString` would be [a] known method", but it really isn't, it's a whole "method group" (the C# term for a set of overloaded functions).  And `dynamic` prevents the compiler from resolving which of them will be called, so it doesn't know the return type.  It so happens in this case that all possible overloads (based on parameter count) return the same type, but trying to find common types across a method group is not part of the contract for `dynamic` (Another similar idea would be detecting if all the methods require a second parameter of common type)

Comment: Is there a way to specify what is constrained and what is not, perhaps by using wrappers? How *could* you choose the overload at run time while specifying that the return type or other parameters are known at compike time?

Comment: @JDługosz See an update to my answer.  Basically you add a cast to bind downstream calls at compile-time.

Comment: @Servy yes i'm surprised. The compiler absolutely has the information to know this is an impossible scenario. It's really annoying how stupid they made dynamic. Too stupid to understand this impossible scenario, too "smart" to prevent access to private/internal members. And no sane way to check if a member is defined. I really wish dynamic didn't suck horribly.

Comment: It would have to check at link time, as all forms are not necessarily known when this file is compiled?  You could add one later, or in another file.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic The compiler *doesn't* have the information to know that this is impossible because it's *not* impossible.  It's entirely possible that the code *can* work when this code is run.  If you think "dynamic" really sucks then it's a pretty strong sign that you're trying to use it in contexts it wasn't designed to be used.  If you want the compiler to be doing type checking then *don't use `dynamic`.